# Got 2,919 PB/s in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have problem (seems to be trivia) about Ubuntu Terminal. Once my network connection slow down then it (sometimes but very rare to happened) showed some information like this.

[image]

I shocked because I have been got 2,919 PB/s. Sorry my mouse block some part of letter 'P' (I actually rush to print screen) but I believe you can recognize it.

---

**EDIT**

---

based on answer given to me, and I got similar info then, I'd like to add more clearly new image after.

[image]

Can someone explain it to me?

Best Regards!

Comment: I am very happy because I can reproduce my problem when I asked it at askUbuntu.com, hope it will help to understands my problem. thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a measuring error. The download speed is measured by dividing the amount of data downloaded by the time passed since the download was started. If you do that after only one IP packet has arrived, you can get weird results.

Comment: I am confused. Can it rephrase to some rational calculation?? ^^

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I used the word "package" instead of "packet". Suppose every second, 50 packets arrive with 200 B of data. This would mean a download speed of 10kb/s. However, let's say you start measuring, and the first packet arrives after 1 millisecond. Your best estimate of the download speed at that point would be 200 kB/s instead of 10. Only after more packets have arrived, your measurement will get closer to the real value.

Comment: and then, with same analogy, can you explain how I will get 2,919 PB/s??, I will add new image after (a got some similar with) at my EDIT post. ^^

Comment: Well, perhaps I could, but the point is: it may be a calculation error or a bad assumption made by the algorithm. My guess is that the reported value will drop to a more reasonable level very soon afterwards. If it remains that high for a prolonged time you should maybe report a bug.