# What is pb/s in terms of downloading speed

Tags: 19.04

I was upgrading my ubuntu dist to version 19.04 and it said 1,2 pB/s. I think it is petabytes(or bits, idk which for sure) per second. Is that a bug, or doesnt mean peta?

Comment: We were not there, so did not see what you saw. When we upgrade, exactly what should we do and where/when should we be looking to see it?

Comment: More likely pico not peta and your net connection was having a bad day.

Comment: I've seen this pB/s thing happen during updates when my connection is particularly slow. Someone else saw it as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/321383/got-2-919-pb-s-in-ubuntu-terminal

Comment: Here's another example: https://forum.vivaldi.net/post/117963 related to very slow download speeds.

Comment: Seems to be an unresolved bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1375405 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=809148